# How to print Maximum of date1 and max of date2 for date1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My Table is like this:

```
ID    DATE1         DATE2
-----------------------------
1   17-Dec-14   17-Mar-15
1   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
1   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
1   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
2   17-Dec-14   17-Mar-15
2   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
2   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
2   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
2   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
2   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
2   27-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
2   17-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
2   17-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
1   17-Dec-14   16-Dec-14
1   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
1   27-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
1   17-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
1   17-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
```

I want output as the following:

```
ID     DATE1        DATE2
------------------------------
1   17-Dec-14   17-Mar-15
2   17-Dec-14   17-Mar-15
1   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
2   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
1   27-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
2   27-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
1   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
2   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
```

I've written query as

```
SELECT  ID,DATE1,MAX(DATE2) FROM(
      SELECT ID,MAX(DATE1)DATE1 ,DATE2 FROM (
                SELECT ID,DATE1,DATE2 FROM
                                      ABC )GROUP BY ID,DATE2)
                                      GROUP BY ID,DATE1
                                      ORDER BY DATE1 DESC
```

But, I'm not getting required output.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: Answer given by @Randy is different than your requirement but it seems like he catched your requirement .... why "1   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15" twice in answer?
Answer given by Randy also give "1   17-Nov-14   19-Mar-15" which is not in your desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

hard to understand your request.  Is it this simple?

```
select id, date1, max(date2)
from abc
group by id, date1
```

Comment: Randy/Nagendra, My requirement is "I want to print the miximum value of date1 based on ABC table and maximum value of the date2 that is been associated with the date1. Eg: 17-Dec-2014 is the highest date of date1 and 17-Mar-2014 is the highest date of date2 that is been associated with date1.  Similarly for,                                                       1   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
2   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
1   27-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
2   27-Nov-14   19-Mar-15
1   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15
2   7-Dec-14    19-Mar-15. And, o/p has to be displayed for both id's

Comment: this made even less sense to me.. sorry